# Zermelo-Fraenkel axiom of separation

Tags: set-theory

The axiom (scheme) of separation as stated by my lecturer is $$(\forall t_1)\dots(\forall t_n)(\forall x)(\exists y)(\forall z)(z\in y\iff z\in x\wedge p),$$ for each formula $p$ with free variables $t_1,\dots t_n,z$. The slogan he attached to it reads "can form subsets".

Wikipedia phrases this more precisely as "a definable subclass of a set is a set" - I believe the word definable here refers to the fact that we need a formula $p$ characterising the elements of $x$ we're interested in.

I'm kind of unclear on what this actually means - what language is the formula allowed to be over? Is it perhaps the language of ZF set theory, which has no functions and a single predicate $\in$? This seems strange to me - how will I for instance form the subset of $\mathbb{N}$ given by the even numbers if I'm not allowed to use $+$?

Furthermore, even if I'm e.g allowed to use the language of Peano Arithmetic, a challenge given by the lecturer earlier that I haven't been able to complete yet is to show the subset of $\mathbb{N}$ given by the powers of 6 is definable. Does this mean that I can't honestly refer to the "set of powers of 6" before I've solved the exercise? That seems absurd to me - surely the axiom of separation should imply e.g that any subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is a set, rather than just the countably many definable ones?

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: Since it seems to address your question, I've turned my comments into an answer after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first guess is correct: separation applies **only** to formulas in the "pure" language of set theory. But nothing is lost, since in $\mathsf{ZFC}$-style foundations everything is implemented purely set-theoretically. For example, $\mathbb{N}$ is standardly implemented as the *finite ordinals*. This has definite drawbacks - even simple operations on natural numbers, like addition, become rather complicated to describe set-theoretically (nothing nearly so simple as "union"!) - but does work: all mathematics can be "faithfully implemented" into set theory alone.

Various posts at this site and mathoverflow treat the issues that arise from this; in particular, the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90820/set-theories-without-junk-theorems) might be relevant.